# Onedrive download always local

Tags: sharepoint, dropbox, onedrive

I am planning a big migration from Dropbox to Microsoft Onedrive but i noticed that Onedrive does not offer the same download logic as Dropbox. To be precise, we really liked the feature from dropbox where the files are pre-downloaded in your computer and when you really need them you dont have to download.

Unfortunatelly from what i see, Onedrive does not offer the same option.

The reason we are trying to do this, its to minize wait time when you really need the files.

Anyone who encountered this program?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

By default onedrive data will be on cloud to save your local storage and for colloboration.

If you want to use it local, there is an option avaiable in onedrive after sync.

**Right click on required folder > Always keep on this device**.

Now these files will be aviable locally even onedrive sync offline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know that i can do it folder by folder but i was looking for a faster way..